# Netbeans Java WebcamCapture Throws Exception

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, webcam

Using Netbeans, I'm trying to connect my laptop camera, or another USB camera and take a screenshot. I have two classes in my project for doing that:

1. functiiwebcam.java (it contains all the functions for connecting the device and capture image)

   This is the code:

   ```
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import javax.media.*;
   import javax.media.cdm.CaptureDeviceManager;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl;
   import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
   import javax.media.util.BufferToImage;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class functiiwebcam {
       //pentru fereastra, implicit dispozitiv   
       String camera = "vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";
       Player broadcast = null;

       public Component Componente() {
           Component componente_video;

           try {
               // Selectare dispozitiv
               CaptureDeviceInfo device = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(camera);
               //Sursa imaginilor capturate
               MediaLocator localizador = device.getLocator();
               //Locatia este de tipul "vfw://0" video para windows
               //Fereastra pentru afisarea imaginilor in aplicatie
               broadcast = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(localizador);
               //broadcast.start();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
              // Logger.getLogger(functiiwebcam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               ex.printStackTrace();
           } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(functiiwebcam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(functiiwebcam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }

           // Obtinerea imaginilor in player
           if ((componente_video = broadcast.getVisualComponent()) != null) {
               //dimensiunea ferestrei de broadcast
               componente_video.setSize(320, 240);
               return componente_video;
           } else {

               return null;
           }
       }

       // Metoda pentru captura imaginii
       Image img = null;
       public void capturareImagine() {
           FrameGrabbingControl ControlFG = (FrameGrabbingControl) broadcast.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
           Buffer buffer = ControlFG.grabFrame();
           // creare image awt
           BufferToImage image = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buffer.getFormat());
           img = image.createImage(buffer);
       }

       public Image getImage() {
           return img;
       }

       public void setImage(JLabel lb) {
           capturareImagine();        
           lb.setIcon( new javax.swing.ImageIcon( img ) );
           System.out.println("ancho= " + img.getWidth(null));
           System.out.println("alto= " + img.getHeight(null));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Webcam.java (which contains the design SWING GUI -JFRAME FORM :the buttons and the panels etc.)

   Here, I don't think you need the entire code. It's generated by Netbeans when I designed the interface. I'll put just the class:

   ```
   import javax.swing.Icon;
   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class Webcam extends javax.swing.JFrame {
       functiiwebcam b = new functiiwebcam();
       /** Creates new form Webcam */
       public Webcam() {
           initComponents();
           this.setTitle("Webcam");
           // Centreaza ferestra
           this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           // Aplicare Layout de tip BOX panoului cu numele broadcast (cel in care se afiseaza imaginile de pe webcam)       
           broadcast.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(broadcast, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
           // Adaugarea componentei video
           broadcast.add(b.Componente());
       }

       // Button for webcam capture
       private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           b.capturareImagine();

           Icon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(b.getImage());
           captura.setIcon(icon);
   ```

When I run the application it throws me this exception. But it's curious that sometimes it works; I can select the device from the window that appears and I can see the image from the webcam and even capture it. What is wrong?

```
java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device
java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device
Iun 05, 2012 1:48:54 PM functiiwebcam Componente
SEVERE: null
javax.media.NoPlayerException: Error instantiating class: com.sun.media.protocol.vfw.DataSource : java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForContent(Manager.java:1362)
    at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:417)
    at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:553)
    at functiiwebcam.Componente(functiiwebcam.java:37)
    at Webcam.<init>(Webcam.java:30)
    at MediaPlayer.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(MediaPlayer.java:476)
    at MediaPlayer.access$900(MediaPlayer.java:17)
    at MediaPlayer$11.actionPerformed(MediaPlayer.java:325)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at functiiwebcam.Componente(functiiwebcam.java:48)
    at Webcam.<init>(Webcam.java:30)
    at MediaPlayer.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(MediaPlayer.java:476)
    at MediaPlayer.access$900(MediaPlayer.java:17)
    at MediaPlayer$11.actionPerformed(MediaPlayer.java:325)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Means sometimes it runs and sometimes throws exception?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: No.it always throws exception: java.io.IOException: Could not connect to capture device   ---but sometimes it passes it and display what i need,sometimes it doesn't ,it gets stuck there.

Comment: The word _sometimes_ makes me think of threading problems.